# Does open circuit affect the voltage of V_s?

Tags: circuit-analysis

In the above circuit, how do we identity the voltage of V_s is it through the right most branch or the one to its left? also whats V_e in this case? Also what if the roles were reversed if the left branch containing the positively oriented E is open, then whats V_s in that case, would I extract it from the circuit to its right?

[image]

Comment: please annotate your image – give all the components names.

Comment: what componenet are you confused about?

Comment: all of them. Label them, please. Due to size and fuzzyness of your pencil writing, I can barely read the indices next to the V, too. Also, don't use the same symbol "E" for two different things in the same schematic, that just makes referring to either of them hard.

Comment: You made things worse by using the symbol "R" for two different things. Come on, you can do better. \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ would be an option. Do the same for your \$E\$s.

Comment: @MarcusMüller they are the same resistances, same the generators E they are the same just different orientation

Comment: but they are not the same component. When I say "no current flows through R", you don't know which one I meant.

Comment: ah excellent i see what you mean

Comment: \$V_S = E_1 = V_e\$ for your first question.

Comment: \$E_1\$ ( written `\$E_1\$`) is the only defined voltage source so no, it is as as I state.

Comment: @Andyaka but you arent considering the resistances?

Comment: The resistances don't form a potential divider when E1 is the only source. The resistances are irrelevant to Vs equalling E1.

Comment: @Andyaka because since E_1 is supplying the circuit, then there must be a current going thru the resistance and no forgetting V_e, thats why i thought V_s = V_e + R * i

Comment: Is there anything connected to where you show \$V_e\$ or, is it an open circuit?

Comment: V_e is the input tension its a sinusoidal voltage = V_m*sin(wt)